# jquery-jtable if condition is met do action

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-jtable

I am using jtable (jtable.org) and have created a table like I want. What I cannot figure out how to do is make an if statement around the action `'createAction'`

There is an object in the jtable api called:

> TotalRecordCount: Total count of records (not only this page).

What I want is something like:

> if(TotalRecordCount < 5){ createAction:
>   'PersonActionsPagedSorted.php?orderId=&action=create', }

Here is the entire code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
//Prepare jTable
jQuery('#ext_table').jtable({
//title: 'Create Extensions',
paging: true,
pageSize: 10,
sorting: true,
defaultSorting: 'Extension ASC',
actions: {
listAction: 'PersonActionsPagedSorted.php?orderId=&action=list',
createAction: 'PersonActionsPagedSorted.php?orderId=&action=create',
updateAction: 'PersonActionsPagedSorted.php?action=update',
deleteAction: 'PersonActionsPagedSorted.php?action=delete'
},
fields: {
PersonId: {
key: true,
create: false,
edit: false,
list: false
},
Name: {
title: 'Name',
width: '30%',
sorting:false,
//inputClass: 'validate[required]'
},
emailAddress: {
title: 'Email Address',
width: '20%',
sorting:false
}
});
//Load person list from server
$('#ext_table').jtable('load');
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, $recordCount is set by a SQL query much like:

```
    $sql_select = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS RecordCount FROM myTable";
    $stmt = $conn->query($sql_select);
    $result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $recordCount = $result['RecordCount'];
```

That set variable is then inserted into the $jTableResult array with the ['TotalRecordCount'] indice sort of like this:

```
    $jTableResult['TotalRecordCount'] = $recordCount;
```

I say this to clarify that the $recordcount variable is already available to php without trying to extract it from jtable itself (that is, it isn't GET or POST data from the jtable).

Now then, in your jtable configuration file where you specify the fields and actions and such you can do something like this:

```
    actions: {
                listAction: 'actions.php?action=list',
    <?php if($recordCount <5) { ?>
               createAction: 'actions.php?orderId=&action=create',
    <?php }else{ ?>
               createAction: 'actions.php?action=create',
    <?php } ?>
                updateAction: 'actions.php?action=update',
                deleteAction: 'actions.php?action=delete'
            },
```

I am positive this works because I use the same method to check a $_SESSION variable to determine whether or not certain actions are made available to the user.